# How to serve static html from arbitrary url path in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I would like to serve `example.com/mypage.html` from `example.com/mypage`.

Within nginx.conf I tried putting `mypage.html` in designated root directory and then

```
location /mypage}
 alias mypage.html;
}
```

But no dice. Must be something similar?

Edit: If I put entire path from '/' in alias it works but I would rather have it relative from the set root directory. How do I reference the root dir I have defined earlier in the config with:

```
root /usr/share/nginx/www;
```

Further, when I do this and the client makes a request for /mypage, nginx defaults to octet stream filetype. How do I force text/html for URLs I define like this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add the following to your `location /` block to make it work for all pages. This will first try to serve the requested uri, if that doesn't work it will try to serve it with an html extension (without adding it to the url)

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

or if you want it only to work with one page you can add the following to your server block

```
location ~ /mypage {
    try_files $uri.html /index.html;
}
```

Comment: what is the ~ for?

Comment: Check this page for the various regex options: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location

Comment: @user1561108 "~" for **case sensitive** matching [#1](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location)